# Shopify paginate limit

Tags: jquery, shopify, liquid

How to limit the pagination using dropdown 
  paginate collection.products by 12

```
select                     
     option selected="select" View as 16 items/page option
           select
       endpaginate
```

Comment: I thing, you should show more of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to create a select dropdown like this.

[image]

To do that first you need to add new collection template, name it as collection.12.liquid . Repeat the process to create more templates like 16 , 24 , 32 as you need.

[image]

Now edit each template and change the pagination limit code for each template accordingly.

`{% paginate collection.products by 12 %}`

or

`{% paginate collection.products by 16 %}`

Now you can create the select dropdown for changing to different pagination templates by using `?view=XX` parameter

example :

`https://your-shop.myshopify.com/collections/bags?view=16
https://your-shop.myshopify.com/collections/bags?view=24
https://your-shop.myshopify.com/collections/bags?view=32`

Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks

Comment: @LanierAglibot , You are most welcome. If the solution works for you please accept my answer. Feel free to ask me if you have any questions.